# Design of math paper - small toc and different header style

Tags: table-of-contents, book-design

In this given link:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/370511972_On_homology_theories_of_cubical_digraphs
you can see the preview of a math paper. I really like the design and I tried to tex it but some problems occured.

So the title and the name can be done like this:

```
    \begin{center}
    \textbf{Title of math paper}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \textsc{Authors}
\end{center}
```

But how can you do this small table of contents and how can you change the style of the sections like this? Also, the ,,Abstract" is not aligned with the text below.  If someone could provide a brief outline (with lipsum text or something like this) of the first half page, it would greatly assist me, I hope its not too much asked.

This one has a similar style:
[https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2012/REUPapers/LiAng.pdf](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2012/REUPapers/LiAng.pdf)

Comment: See the [`amsart` document class](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsart)